# File Not Found Exception when installing CloudStack version 4.7.0.0

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I've been trying to install `CloudStack version 4.7.0.0` and on startup I get the following messages (see below). When I ls -l on the file it does exist.

-rw-------. 1 cloud root   2231 May 11 13:08 cloudmanagementserver.keystore

Anyone one have any ideas?

```
May 11, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint adjustRelativePath
WARNING: configured file:    [/etc/cloudstack/management/cloudmanagementserver.keystore] does not exist.
May 11, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/cloudstack/management/cloudmanagementserver.keystore (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.init(NioEndpoint.java:836)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol.init(Http11NioProtocol.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1007)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

May 11, 2016 12:45:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
SEVERE: Catalina.start
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/cloudstack/management/cloudmanagementserver.keystore (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1009)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

Kind regards,
Michele

Answer (score 0):

So I took a look at a previous version (I had to go back to version 4.2 as 4.5 has a bug and doesn't create this file at all) and saw that it was just a matter of permissions. I've changed them as specified below:

[vagrant@mgmt-server1 management]$ sudo chown root:root

[vagrant@mgmt-server1 management]$ sudo chmod 644 cloudmanagementserver.keystore

This resolved that issue in the startup catalina.out log.

Thanks if anyone looked at this.

Comment: In addition, if anyone Installs CloudStack 4.5.0.0 from scratch, there is a bug where the cloudmanagementserver.keystore file is not created and you will need to create it yourself